# Android Lifecycle in Adobe Air

Tags: android, air, adobe, android-activity, onpause

How are events like onPause, onResume etc for Android Activity taken care of in Adobe Air. I want to do something when activity is paused while developing AIR app how do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read this article by [Oliver Goldman](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/author_bios/oliver_goldman.html),  http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/considerations-air-apps-mobile.html . It says that we can use flash.events.Event.DEACTIVATE event of AIR to keep a tab on onPause. More info on -  http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/reference/html/flash/desktop/NativeApplication.html